# Grammatical origins of names in Tanach

Tags: names, grammar-dikduk, etymology

Almost all nouns in Hebrew fit into one of several standard "templates". For example, מִבְחָן comes from the root בחנ combined with the pattern מִפְעָל (already used by many other words). There would never be a word like מֻבְחֵן, since its pattern does not exist anywhere else.

Throughout Tanach, many people's names are explicitly connected to a specific word. For example, שִׁמְעוֹן was named because HaShem heard (שָׁמַע) Leah's prayers. Do these names also fit into patterns? Did Leah simply combine the root שׁמע with a some random vowels and a nice suffix, or did she use a standard "template" to come up with the name?